# Add-Migration в .NET Core 1.0.0 . Ошибки при "OpenFile"

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-core

Развлекают разными штуками с **.NET** Core второй день. Почти справился с **Add-Migration**, но тут появляется

```
Add-Migration : Исключение при вызове "OpenFile" с "1" аргументами: "Параметр задан неверно. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80070057 
(E_INVALIDARG))"строка:1 знак:1
+ Add-Migration Arajan
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Migration], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation,Add-Migration
```

Что это? Я уже не в состоянии это терпеть. Эту загадку я не могу решить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Забейте на эту ошибку. Дело в том, что просто не открывает файл миграции для просмотра. Так то миграция создается. Делайте дальше Update-Database и будет вам счастье.